# LIKE operator in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Is it possible using LIKE operator to write a query to find values that residing in a numeric datatype column?

For example,

Table sample

```
ID | VALUE(numeric)

1  | 1.00
2  | 2.00

select * from sample where VALUE LIKE '1%'
```

Please clear my doubt...

Comment: How to get values using pattern matching??

Comment: `select * from num12 where value::text like '1%'` will works

Comment: Here what text denotes??

Comment: To clarify : what's your actual need ??

Comment: value is a `numeric` field in your table in order to work `like` in that field you need to cast as it to text `value::text`

Comment: What make you think to use `LIKE` when you can use `where value=1.00` in the select ?

Comment: `LIKE` is for character values, not for numbers. What is the **real** problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Maybe `WHERE value >= 1 AND value < 2` will do the job? Don't know if it's even faster than using `trunc()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly then following could be a solution for you

consider this sample

```
create table num12 (id int,VALUE numeric);

insert into  num12 values (1,1.00),(2,2.00);
insert into  num12 values (3,1.50),(4,1.90);
```

the table look like

```
id value 
-- ----- 
1  1.00  
2  2.00  
3  1.50  
4  1.90
```

---

```
select * from num12 where value =1
```

will return only single row,

```
id value 
-- ----- 
1  1.00
```

If you want to select all `1`s then use(*I guess you're trying to find a solution for this*)

```
select * from num12 where trunc(value) =1
```

result:

```
id value 
-- ----- 
1  1.00  
3  1.50  
4  1.90
```

---

> Is it possible using LIKE operator to write a query to find values
>   that residing in a numeric datatype column?
>
> *Answer*: **Yes**

You can use `select * from num12 where value::text like '1%'`

*Note :* *It yields same result as shown above but its **`not`** a good method*

Comment: Yeah, given queries are working fine... I had to clarify my doubts.. that is it.. Thank you